# How to manage accents in UISearchbar?

Tags: ios, json, uisearchbar

well I have a big toruble.
Im parsing a JSON in a tableview with a UISearchBarController, so my app is in spanish and some of the json entries  have accents and when I make the search ex. if im looking for "México" I type "Mexico" and the result is nil because I didnt write the accent in the search.

So the question is, ¿How can I solve this? I want the accents be invisible for the search. Hope I explain well

Heres the searchbar method:

```
NSMutableArray *allObject;
    NSMutableArray *displayObject;


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
    {
        if([searchString length] == 0)
        {
            [displayObject removeAllObjects];
            [displayObject addObjectsFromArray:allObject];
        }
        else
        {
            [displayObject removeAllObjects];
            for(NSDictionary *tmpDict in allObject)
            {
                NSString *val = [tmpDict objectForKey:doctorname];
                NSRange r = [val rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                NSString *val2 = [tmpDict objectForKey:doctoresp];
                NSRange r2 = [val2 rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                NSString *val3 = [tmpDict objectForKey:direccion];
                NSRange r3 = [val3 rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];


                if(r2.location != NSNotFound || r.location != NSNotFound || r3.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    [displayObject addObject:tmpDict];
                }
            }
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` option, so e will match é.

Comment: How can I have both NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch options? thanks.

Comment: @Karlo Just OR the two options: `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`.